# WPF-Binding is broken when View is closed and reopened

Tags: wpf, mvvm, data-binding, datacontext

I have a View (MainWindow.Xaml) which has a datacontext set to the MainWindowViewModel and I open it from the MainUIService like the code below.

```
public class MainUIService 
{
    void IMainUIService.Show()
    {
        var viewModel = ViewModelSource.Create(() => new MainWindowViewModel());
        var mainUI = new MainWindow();
        mainUI.DataContext = viewModel;
        System.Windows.Application.Current.MainWindow = mainUI;
        mainUI.Show();
    }
}
```

My requirement is to close and Reopen the View from the MainWindowViewModel.Now the problem here is none of the bindings are working.I was trying to set the text for a textblock inside the MainWindow.xaml after ReOpening it.

```
<TextBlock x:Name="CurrentUserName" Padding="2" Background="{Binding 
   EnvironmentBackgroundColor}" Foreground="White" Text="{Binding UserName}"/>
```

I tried INotifyPropertyChanged,Mode=2way,IsAsyn=True and various solutions from internet,but nothing seems to work.

Is there any way I can achieve this?Please help